# Optimizing jquery hide() and show() on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a site with a large outline, and I'm trying to let our users filter it down so they can see just the stuff they want. Each line of the outline has a set of classes that say what category it's in, and I'm hide/showing them via jQuery when the users select a particular category.

Here's the current location so you can see it in action:

https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:HarvardX+CHEM160+1T2017/76695c0ad7604bb897570ecb906db6e3/

And here's the javascript and css for this page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('working');

  // Keeping track of all the currently visible items.
  var currentlyShown = [];
  var index;
  var showAllButton = $('#showAll');

  // If any of the object's classes match any of the selected options, show it.
  function showRightClasses() {
    console.log('showing: ' + currentlyShown);
    if (currentlyShown.length == 0) {
      showAllButton.click();
    }

    $('.hiddenpage').each(function(i) {
      if (_.intersection(this.className.split(' '), currentlyShown).length > 0) {
        $(this).show('slow');
      } else {
        $(this).hide('slow');
      }
    });
  }

  if (showAllButton.prop('checked')) {
    currentlyShown.push('hiddenpage');
    showRightClasses();
  }

  showAllButton.change(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
      index = currentlyShown.indexOf('hiddenpage');
      if (index !== -1) {
        currentlyShown.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } else {
      currentlyShown.push('hiddenpage');
    }
    showRightClasses();
  });

  $('.pageselector').change(function() {
    subject = $(this).attr('name');
    if (!this.checked) {
      index = currentlyShown.indexOf(subject);
      if (index !== -1) {
        currentlyShown.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } else {
      currentlyShown.push(subject);
    }
    if (showAllButton.prop('checked')) {
      showAllButton.click();
    }
    showRightClasses();
  });

});
```

```css
.hiddenpage {
  display: none;
}

.checkboxes {
  float: right;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 4px outset #aaa;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.checkboxes label {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-section {
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.nav-sub {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.nav-unit {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

This *works*, but on Safari it's dreadfully slow, and it's not particularly fast on Firefox either. Is there a more efficient way to hide/show the rows in this outline without losing the animation? Am I accidentally doing something foolish like having every row run code that hides every other row?

I should note that I have no ability to control the rest of the environment. I can't change the version of jQuery that the site uses, or remove Underscore, for example. I can only control the code you see above, and the HTML for the list.

Comment: Why don't you just add/remove class on the parent and use CSS to hide/animate?

Comment: @Huangism I haven't tried that approach before; is it faster than hide() and show()?

Comment: 100% it will be faster because all your doing is adding/removing classes with js. The main issue with your lag is due to the js animation as mention in the answer below

Comment: @Huangism as it turns out, YES. Much. (Edit: whoops, crosspost. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you care about speed, ditch the 'slow' param in `.show('slow')` and `.hide('slow')`. This triggers a very performance-heavy jQuery animation.

With all the frames you're loosing right now, this will not work nice anyway. If you need animation there, maybe you could try something with opacity instead, since (css-based) opacity animation is very cheap.

EDIT: just checked this on the site you linked and it works nice and snappy with just `.show()` and `.hide()`. The 'slow' param is definitely your bottleneck, so either just remove it or look for a different way to animate, if you absolutely need to.

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely it. I combined your answer with @Huangism 's suggestion about using css transitions. My new version uses transitions on max-height for the animation, then uses hide/show with no arguments. As a side note, I also set aria-hidden attributes in a vain attempt to get VoiceOver to skip the hidden elements on Firefox. No luck. (Browser issue, I believe.) Still works in VoiceOver on Safari and Chrome.

Comment: aria-hidden should work, the other option is to hide it after the animation is done and screen readers will skip